# Spiderable and Iron-Router example

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Does someone uses Iron-Router and Spiderable-404?
Please I need some complete examples to show me how to add the metatags.

They say this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.Router.add({
    '/': 'index',
    '/a': 'a',
    '/b': function() {
      Spiderable.httpHeaders['X-Foo'] = 'bar';
      return 'b';
    },
    '*': function() {
      Spiderable.httpStatusCode = 404;
      return 'notFound';
    }
  });
}
```

but this does not work in iron router and there is no meta tag in this poor example, or I could not make it work, please help me fill the blanks.

Comment: What result are you expecting and what do you actually get?

Comment: I need to add meta data in my site.
<meta name="description" content="Text">
<meta name="author" content="#">
<meta name="copyright" content="someinfo" />
<meta name="application-name" content="SomeInfo" />

Then, spiderable came in the results, now, I just need the example, how to pass this meta data for the router because just adding these lines in the headers is not working.

Answer (score 2):

The spiderable package is just a package you install and forget in Meteor. You do not use it directly from within your app.

Meteor SEO is not very mature, but you have options to get basic SEO working. Especially when you are using iron-router, there is the [ms-seo](https://github.com/DerMambo/ms-seo) smart package that you can use as:

```
$ mrt add ms-seo
```

and then in your router configuration:

`Router.map(function() {
  return this.route('blogPost', {
    path: '/blog/:slug',
    waitOn: function() {
      return [Meteor.subscribe('postFull', this.params.slug)];
    },
    data: function() {
      var post;
      post = Posts.findOne({
        slug: this.params.slug
      });
      return {
        post: post
      };
    },
    onAfterAction: function() {
      var post;
      // The SEO object is only available on the client.
      // Return if you define your routes on the server, too.
      if (!Meteor.isClient) {
        return;
      }
      post = this.data().post;
      SEO.set({
        title: post.title,
        meta: {
          'description': post.description
        },
        og: {
          'title': post.title,
          'description': post.description
        }
      });
    }
  });
});`

Also for 404 responses, iron-router's standard `notFoundTemplate` already provides the HTTP status code out of box. For other status codes, you need to define [server side routes](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#server-side-routing)

````
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('serverFile', {
    where: 'server',
    path: '/files/:filename',

```
action: function () {
  var filename = this.params.filename;

  this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  this.response.end('hello from server');
}
```

});
});
````

*PS: You may want to refer to this [blog post](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteor-and-seo), and [this one](http://journal.gentlenode.com/meteor-12-seo-guide/) for further reading.*

*PPS: Your router configuration looks generally wrong. Your code looks like it belongs to the outdated meteor-router package. Refer to the [iron-router package docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md) for more information.*

Comment: Yep, I've read the Manuel Schoebel blog as well :) Thanks, but it is not working in facebook so far, I let you know how it was.

Comment: Serkan, my console say SEO is undefined, I've tryed to remove and mrt add again and nothing, any ideas?

Comment: In order for spiderable to work, you should first install phantomjs on your server. After that, when you curl http://localhost:3000 if you get a result, then facebook should work as well. if not, then the problem is not facebook and we should look more into your app.